# User select a radio button from rails form and then immediately be given more form options - coffeescript fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I am trying to have a user select a radio button and immediately be given more form options based on that radio option.  The Divs correctly hide initially as per below, but the fields do not display based on the radio button option.   Initially I was going to have the coffeescript try to grab the radio buttons via $("input:radio[name='example']"), but the name is different for each one since the "steps" in which the radio buttons exist are created and deleted by the user, and as a result have a different name for each.  Any help would be appreciated.

Coffeescript

```
$(".excelCreator").hide()
$(".videoCreator").hide()
$(".mcCreator").hide()
$(".stepRadio").change ->
  if @value is "video" and @checked
    $(".videoCreator").show()
  else if @value is "excel" and @checked
    $(".excelCreator").show()
  else if @value is "multiple_choice" and @checked
    $(".mcCreator").show()
  else
    $(".excelCreator").hide()
    $(".videoCreator").hide()
    $(".mcCreator").hide()
```

Here is the show view with the radio buttons

```
 <div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :media_type, "Excel" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :media_type, 'excel', :checked => true, class: 'icheck stepRadio' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :media_type, "Video" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :media_type, 'video', class: 'icheck stepRadio' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :media_type, "Multiple Choice" %>
      <%= f.radio_button :media_type, 'multiple_choice', class: 'icheck stepRadio' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the options I would like shown based upon the radio buttons above in the same view

```
<div class="excelCreator">
    <%= f.label :link, "Excel Link" %>
    <%= f.text_field :link, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :answer, "Excel Answer (#)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :answer, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
</div>

<div class="videoCreator">
    <%= f.label :link, "Video Link" %>
    <%= f.text_field :link, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
</div>

<div class="mcCreator">
    <%= f.label :choice_one, "Choice One" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_one, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :choice_two, "Choice Two" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_two, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :choice_three, "Choice Three" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_three, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :choice_four, "Choice Four" %>
    <%= f.text_field :choice_four, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
    <%= f.label :answer, "MC Answer (#)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :answer, :style => "width: 98%;" %>
</div>
```

here is an example of the html that is output for one of the form fields

```
 <div>
      <label for="course_levels_attributes_0_steps_attributes_0_media_type">Excel</label>
      <input checked="checked" class="icheck stepRadio" id="course_levels_attributes_0_steps_attributes_0_media_type_excel" name="course[levels_attributes][0][steps_attributes][0][media_type]" type="radio" value="excel" />
    </div>
```

Comment: If they all have 'example' in their name, you could use `$("input:radio[name*='example']")`. The `*=` operator searches for the given pattern, rather than matching the whole string.

Comment: The first three lines of the coffeescript work, meaning all of the divs are hidden, however, one of the three 'friends' should show up based on which radio button is clicked and it is not showing up